# pandas duplicated row values to single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame.

| date | data | meter_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-13 | a | 1 |
| 2023-02-13 | b | 2 |
| 2023-02-13 | c | 6 |
| 2023-02-10 | d | 1 |
| 2023-02-08 | e | 1 |
| 2023-02-08 | f | 2 |
| 2023-02-05 | g | 1 |
| 2023-02-02 | h | 2 |

I want to convert it to following unique date and columns equal unique meter_id.

| date | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-13 | a | b | c |
| 2023-02-10 | d | NaN | NaN |
| 2023-02-08 | e | f | NaN |
| 2023-02-05 | g | NaN | NaN |
| 2023-02-02 | NaN | h | NaN |

Comment: I'm trying   df_col = pd.DataFrame(data=df['date'].unique(), columns=['date']) meters = list(df['meter_id'].unique())
df_col[[x for x in meters]] = str([y for y in df['index']])

Comment: What you need is to pivot the df. pd.pivot_table(df, values='date', index='meter_id, columns=['data'])